# To merge two sorted linked lists. Is there a better way to create new Linked list heads in java?

Tags: java, object, merge, linked-list

In this program, I have created the head node inside the class LinkedList.

```
public class LinkedList {
public class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node next;
}

Node Head=null
void IntersectionOfTwoSortedLists(Node ListA, Node ListB){

    while (ListA!=null && ListB!=null) {
        if (ListA.data == ListB.data){
            System.out.println(ListA.data);
            InsertAtEnd(ListA.data);
        }
        if(ListA.data<ListB.data)
            ListA=ListA.next;
        else
            ListB=ListB.next;
    }
}
```

and the main function in a different class looks like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list2= new LinkedList();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        list.InsertAtEnd(sc.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the list 2 elements");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      list2.InsertAtEnd(sc.nextInt());
    }

    LinkedList intersect= new LinkedList();
    intersect.IntersectionOfTwoSortedLists(list.Head,list2.Head);
```

creating a new object of the linked list class every time a good practice or is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your code is fully working, but may or may not require some improvement, I'd suggest you use [Code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform operations over two different lists in such case you have to create two different objects. you can use copy but here in your case, it will not work because if you do so then update in one list will affect others too.